# TestFlight: Couldn't install on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, testflight

I can install the watch app on my `iPhone` using Xcode fine. But, I get the following error when I (or my beta testers) try to install the watch app using **TestFlight**.

[image]

I found this message on the console. The provisioning profiles are handled by Xcode automatically. 
Previous build of this app had no problem with the Watch app installation via TestFlight, but now even previous builds in TestFlight refuse to install the watch app.
[image]

Comment: I experienced the exact same issue. I see the same error in the console logs as well. When I scroll up a little higher, I see this message too: `No watch app found with bundle ID org.cocoapods.CocoaLumberjack`. So, I'm wondering if it's related to CocoaPods.

Comment: @LoganGauthier Do you also see the error message in the log related to provisioning profiles

Comment: Yea, I saw the same log as what you posted and then scrolled up a bit and saw the log related to CocoaPods/CocoaLumbjerack.

Comment: @LoganGauthier I also get `[ACXDeviceConnectionClient fetchInfoForApplicationWithBundleID:forDeviceWithPairingID:completion:]: 424: No watch app found with bundle ID org.cocoapods.ObjectMapper`. I think CocoaPods may have something to do w/ the problem.

Comment: @LoganGauthier Do you get a warning related to `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` when you do `pod install`?

Comment: I do get a warning for that right now for my main target, but not the watch target. Btw, I'm currently removing CocoaLumberjack from my watch app just to test to see if it will be able to install so we can confirm that it's somehow related to CocoaPods. My coworker and I are both working on this issue, so I'll update you on what we find.

Comment: I'm seeing exactly the same thing (including the cocoapods log). No warnings when running `pod install` here.

Comment: @simon, don't forget to file a bug report with Apple: https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: I've filed a bug with Apple and included a sample project that they can reproduce it with, so hopefully they can resolve it relatively quickly.

Comment: Has anyone actually shipped an app to the store in this state? Does the Apple Watch app work?

Comment: There's a thread going over at the dev forums as well. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/116139

Comment: Also just opened a GitHub issue over at CocoaPods for this since it smells like a issue they may be able to help with... https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8754

Comment: @LoganGauthier Let us know if you get a radar filed? The dev forums thread I linked above references radar #50346984.

Comment: Finally, thanks to @RawMean's tip, I confirmed I am seeing the following in my console logs: `[ACXDeviceConnectionClient fetchInfoForApplicationWithBundleID:forDeviceWithPairingID:completion:]: 424: No watch app found with bundle ID org.cocoapods.XCGLogger`. I do also have ObjectMapper in my pods though.

Comment: I have filed a bug report: #50336347. Just got off the phone with Apple support. They are asking me to send them screenshots and more info. Please also contact them is you have the issue: https://developer.apple.com/contact/#!/topic/SC1104/subtopic/30042/solution/CALL/details

Comment: @RawMean Can you submit the radar to https://openradar.appspot.com as well?

Comment: @simon Our app on the App Store installs fine (same build that we have problems with on TestFlight), so it appears to be safe to ship.

Comment: Just got the is response from Apple DTS: "App Store Connect is aware of your issue now and is looking for a solution.
"

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with TestFlight and Apple has fixed the problem. I can confirm that the watch app installs using TestFlight now. I did not change anything on my side.

Comment: Definitely not yet fixed on my side. I've tried many times with no success. Did you install an update to the TestFlight app?